# How to default CMake environment variable from cache / CLion work-around

Tags: cmake, clion

I'm trying to work around CLion's inability to handle environment variables.

All of my CMake files start with lines like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
include( $ENV{PROJECT_ROOT}/src/global_settings.cmake )
AssureOutOfSourceBuilds()
```

CLion does not know how to read the environment variable which provides the real path to the global include.  As a result, CLion just completely fails to find anything outside of the current directory, as well as throwing errors.

Is there some way to specify a default value for an environment variable in CMake's cache?  I believe CLion correctly reads the CMake cache.

Any other suggestions on how to get around CLion's current weakness?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that CLion correctly reads the CMake cache, you can give the following workaround a try:

```
if (DEFINED ENV{PROJECT_ROOT})
    set (PROJECT_ROOT "$ENV{PROJECT_ROOT}" CACHE PATH "project root" FORCE)
endif()
include( ${PROJECT_ROOT}/src/global_settings.cmake )
```

The `set` command creates a cache variable with the environment variable's value. The cache variable can then be used as a replacement for `$ENV{...}` expressions. The `FORCE` options ensures that the cache variable is kept up to date with the environment variable's value, if it is set at all.

Comment: So the code you suggest will use the environment variable if it is present, but will use the cache value if the environment variable is missing?  Let me test that with CLion and see how it handles it.

Comment: This does not seem to work as expected.  If the environment variable is not set, it clears the value in the cache, resulting in the include() command failing.   What I need is a cache variable which will be used in the absence of the environment variable.

Comment: See updated answer. Only update cache variable if environment variable ist set. The environment variable has to be defined at least once in order for the cache variable to be initialized properly.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that Clion has some unusual behavior with respect to CMake's cache.  At least in all of my tests, Clion kept resetting or clearing a cache variable (PROJECT_ROOT, above) whenever I set it, so @sakra's solution was not reliable.  I have still voted it the answer to be fair to him for all of his effort.

However, I finally found a solution for this problem, here:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-188#comment=27-899992

It is a trick to actually set the environment variable when Clion calls CMake.  Here are the contents of that link above:

> Here's an ugly work-around for people who need to pass environment or
>   set cache variables via -D, in EAP build 140.1221.2.  In Preferences
>   -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Toolchains, change the CMake executable from the bundled CMake executable to a shell script you
>   define which calls an installed actual CMake executable.
>
> Using the Bash shell, it might look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export SOMEPATH=/path/you/need 
/usr/local/bin/cmake "$@"
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-188#comment=27-902108), since CLion 1.0 you can [directly pass CMake options](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/01/clion-eap-cmake-and-build-options/) in `Settings/Preferences - Build, Execution, Deployment - CMake`.

[image: CMake options:]